# Comparing calculated associations vs. logistic regression

Tags: logistic, correlation, feature-selection, moving-average, importance

We are doing an analysis to find some sort of "recommended average training mileage based on race placements" to recommend training mileage to our members to achieve a certain race placement- not to forecast who wins and who does not.

For our running club, I have about 20k data points for runners' race performance. Of note, we measure race-times in top-half of race finishers, did not finish (DNF), training mileage per week, training frequency (levels such as "runs once a week" to "runs twice a day"), and other features.

We used logistic regression to model top-half placement. I find that there is an increasing positive association with placing in the top-half indicated by training frequency. However the predictive $c$-statistic or AUC indicates a value only slightly higher than 0.5 which is close to useless.

I then created buckets of training mileage. I calculated the median of training per week and created a binary category based on upper/lower 50%. The modeled probability differed more significantly. Success probability is 40% for lower-training vs. 65% for the upper-training-amount bucket.

1. Do the results of these models contradict each other?
2. Are there other models I should consider?

Comment: What you are observing is the effect of dichotomizing a continuous variable. In this case, it is inflating the relationship. ¿What do you obtain for a prediction if you return to the logistic model and predict the probability of being in top half for the first and third quartiles for the training milage values?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please adopt a structured approach to writing these summaries: describe the objective, describe the data, say what you did, say what are you trying to understand/achieve. Organizing your thoughts this way helps you as much as it helps others.

Comment: Hi Gregg H - thank you very much! Just to clarify: do you mean between Q1 and median as "first quartile" (and accordingly between median and Q3 as "third quartile"), did I get that right...?

Comment: Hi Adam - I understand where you are coming from and that is of course what I was trying to do... however, I am not a statistics pro (yet), which is probably why my question was a bit less structured (for me, many of those concepts I mentioned are still new, obviously). And, to be honest, I don't understand my own question anymore after your changes... I have no idea what a predictive c-statistic is, nor what AUC means (I looked those terms up, but I still don't understand them)... also, I am not sure if "success probability" differs, that is exactly what I was asking... I just COUNTED...

Comment: ...also, I think I didn't make my question fully clear: I did NOT use logistic regression on the buckets I created AFTERWARDS... I said "I just counted" because I meant I just looked at the results (i.e., all runners with less than 15 miles of training per week were in group one, 40 of them placed in the top-half of 100 races = 40% - and vice-versa for the runners with more than 15 miles... for example). See what I mean? And the predictive accuracy of the model was not 0.5 or 50%, it was basically the same as the overall percentage of runners in all races placing in the top-half. Hope helps!!

Comment: ...so, I did the analysis on 1st and 3rd quartile (as suggested by Gregg H - as I understood it): the accuracy increases slightly, but really only because the mean value increases as well (this is because we have many runners who don't really train at all - they fall out... and very few who train all the time, but also place in the top-50 all the time... they fall out, too). I had already thought about using only the Q1-Q3 range (or 0 - Q3 actually, since the biggest outliers are after Q3... like the guy who runs 105 miles every week)... it looks "more accurate" (logit), but still not...

Comment: ...as much as the "averages" from my bucket exercise would indicate. For example here: https://www.runnersworld.com/run-the-numbers/runners-with-more-training-miles-finish-marathons-faster - a magazine did the same, but they do this via buckets ONLY... I can create similar ones (the finisher thing, not the time - time is pretty correlated to mileage, but since competition varies, the rest is not), but as said, the logistic regression "does not agree" with the assessment :) Again, thanks for all your help - very much appreciated!!